# Use vb.net in windows form app to merge .csv files into datagridview when "columns" are row based, need to pivot

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have a list of .csv files (about 120) inside a directory that I need to merge and export into a single csv file as well as put into an sql server. To do this I was going to have a button that would place all of the csv files information into a datagridview and then export the datagridview to a csv file and also import into the sql table. I can do all of this with the exception of handling the format of the csv file. The csv files are saved in an odd way where the column headers are running down column A and the data is in column B. I essentially need to pivot the table and then upload into the datagridview. I am not sure how to do this:

.csv file example:

EDIT: I have all of the 133 column headers manually added to the Datagridview.

```
 Column A            Column B
Column Header 1      Data for Column Header 1
Column Header 2      Data for column Header 2
 ......                .........
Column Header 133    Data for column Header 133
```

I need the column headers and information to not be in 2 columns like this. I could manually change the csv file with excel but this would be for 100s of files.

Here is my code so far

```
        Try

                Dim thereader As New StreamReader("Y:\Public\Sanmina Production\3-Projector MTF Test\MTFTest_LJ902A180412AT00022_2019-04-10_17-14-11.csv", Encoding.Default)
                Dim sline As String = ""
                Dim colsexpected As Integer = 133
                Do
                    sline = thereader.ReadLine
                    If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                'Dim words() As String = sline.Split(",")
                Dim keptwords As New List(Of String)
                Dim dataentry() As String = sline.Split(",")
                'DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
                For ix As Integer = 0 To 132
                    'DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(ix).Value = dataentry
                    'keptwords.Add(dataentry(1))
                    kkeptwords.
                Next
                Dim sResult As String = ""

                For Each elem As String In keptwords
                    sResult &= elem & " "
                Next

                MsgBox(sResult)
            Loop
                thereader.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try


            'strFileName = Dir()
        'Loop


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

I stopped coding after adding the blank row because I realized what my outcome was going to be.

Comment: Do ALL the csv files have the same number of rows? Is the header data in “Column A” the same for ALL CSV files? A transpose of the data shown (Column A, Column B) would end up being 133 columns with 1 row of data. If the “header” data is the same for ALL CSV files it would appear that reading and adding each one is redundant and unnecessary. It is not clear if all the CSV files are the same structure and only differ in the Column B data.

Comment: In addition, what is the reasoning behind putting this data directly into a `DataGridView`? I am betting either a custom `List<T>` or even a `DataTable` might be a better option while reading the files. The `List<T>` or `DataTable` could then be used as a data source to the grid if you wanted to display the data. I would suggest you step back and re-evaluate what the overall goal is, as it appears you are making this far more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @JohnG Sorry for the delayed response. Yes all the excel files have the same number of rows. They are a data dump from a different program. The column A is the same for all of the csv files. As far as putting it into a datagridview I am doing this so I can look at the data before attempting to merge it into the excel file as well as putting it into the sql database. This will eventually be a tool for internal customers to the company and they will need a datagridview to view the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working optimally now. I have the directory loop working and found out a large portion of the errors were coming from not having the correct blank row added to the correct spot. This code now works fully. However, I ended up using a round about way to skip over unwanted data by looking for the letters MTF or no data in the csv file. Here is the working updated code.

```
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
        lblFile.Text = "Working"
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim RowEdit As Integer = 0
        Dim Files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("Y:\Public\test\", "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        Dim ArrLength As Integer = Files.Length
        Dim ProgressBarStep As Decimal = 100 / ArrLength
        Dim ProgressBarTotal As Decimal = Nothing
        Dim sResult As String = ""
        For Each element As String In Files
            sResult &= element & " "
        Next
        'MsgBox(sResult)

        For Each element As String In Files
            'lblFile.Text = element
            PB1.Value = ProgressBarTotal


            Try
                i = 0
                Using myReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(element)
                    myReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                    myReader.SetDelimiters(",")

                    Dim currentRow As String()
                    While Not myReader.EndOfData
                        Try
                            currentRow = myReader.ReadFields()
                            Dim currentField As String
                            For Each currentField In currentRow
                                If currentField = "" Then
                                    'Must be value
                                    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = currentField
                                    i = i + 1
                                Else

                                    If currentField.Substring(0, 1) = "M" Then

                                        If currentField.Substring(1, 1) = "T" Then

                                            If currentField.Substring(2, 1) = "F" Then
                                                'Skip this one
                                                ' MsgBox("Skip")
                                            Else
                                                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = currentField
                                                i = i + 1
                                            End If
                                        Else
                                            DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = currentField
                                            i = i + 1

                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = currentField
                                        i = i + 1

                                    End If
                                End If

                            Next
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                        End Try
                    End While
                End Using

                DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
                'RowEdit = RowEdit + 1
                'Select bottom row
                Dim nRowIndexLast As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(nRowIndexLast).Selected = True
                Dim CurrentRow1 As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
                Dim results As DataGridViewRow = CType(CurrentRow1.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
                Dim currentindex As Int32 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(currentindex)
                Dim newindex As Int32 = 0
                DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, results)
                ProgressBarTotal = ProgressBarTotal + ProgressBarStep
                i = 0

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        Next
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
    lblFile.Text = "Complete"
```